# Como replicar estos combobox de javascript en Swift

Tags: javascript, ios, swift

Quiero recrear estos combobox que tengo en javascript en Swift para poder seleccionar un país y que me aparezcan solo las ciudades del país que seleccione y no las ciudades de los demás países de la lista.

El problema es que no sé como hacerlo en Swift para que funcione correctamente.

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme, desde ya, muchas gracias.

```html
<body>
  <form name="formulario1" action="#">
   <select class="seleccion" name="cosa" onchange="cambia()">
    <option value="0">Seleccione un país
    <option value="1">Argentina
    <option value="2">Chile
    <option value="3">Brasil
    <option value="4">Perú
   </select>
   
   <select class="seleccion" name="opt">
    <option value="-">-
   </select>
   
  </form>
  
  <script type="text/javascript">
   //1) Definir Las Variables Correspondintes
   var opt_1 = new Array ("-", "Buenos Aires");
   var opt_2 = new Array ("-", "Santiago");
   var opt_3 = new Array ("-", "Brasilia");
   var opt_4 = new Array ("-", "Lima");
   // 2) crear una funcion que permita ejecutar el cambio dinamico
   
   function cambia(){
    var cosa;
    //Se toma el vamor de la "cosa seleccionada"
    cosa = document.formulario1.cosa[document.formulario1.cosa.selectedIndex].value;
    //se chequea si la "cosa" esta definida
    if(cosa!=0){
     //selecionamos las cosas Correctas
     mis_opts=eval("opt_" + cosa);
     //se calcula el numero de cosas
     num_opts=mis_opts.length;
     //marco el numero de opt en el select
     document.formulario1.opt.length = num_opts;
     //para cada opt del array, la pongo en el select
     for(i=0; i<num_opts; i++){
      document.formulario1.opt.options[i].value=mis_opts[i];
      document.formulario1.opt.options[i].text=mis_opts[i];
     }
     }else{
      //si no habia ninguna opt seleccionada, elimino las cosas del select
      document.formulario1.opt.length = 1;
      //ponemos un guion en la unica opt que he dejado
      document.formulario1.opt.options[0].value="-";
      document.formulario1.opt.options[0].text="-";
     }
     //hacer un reset de las opts
     document.formulario1.opt.options[0].selected = true;
     
    }
   
   
  
  </script>
 </body>
```

Comment: Debes implementar un UITextField sustituyendo el teclado por defecto por un inputView de tipo UIPickerView. Acá te dejo un enlace: https://peterwitham.com/swift-archives/how-to-use-a-uipickerview-as-input-for-a-uitextfield/

Comment: Eso quedaria igual a un UiPickerView

Comment: El problema que tengo es que no sé como enlazar dos de estos objetos, haciendo que cambie el segundo picker dependiendo de lo que elija en el primero...